# reverse diff functionality

Tags: linux, batch-file

i have two files a.txt and b.txt
I would like to report to output ONLY when file are same ?

so:

if file same -> report

if file different -> do not report anything

I know that in diff there is a -s option which report when file are the same but when file are different it will report as well (and I want to not report when files are different)

oh one more think I am not able to install anything additional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are, if you have `diff` available, you will have `grep` available too.  So pipe the `diff` output through `grep` to check which result you get, and act accordingly.  `diff -qs` will output "Files a.txt and b.txt are identical" or "Files a.txt and b.txt differ".  So you can check for the presence of "identical" in the output to find your case.

```
if diff -qs a.txt b.txt | grep -q identical; then
   echo "Files are identical.  Reporting"
else
   # Do nothing
fi
```

Or as a oneliner:

```
(diff -qs a.txt b.txt | grep -q identical) && echo "Files are identical."
```

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question `linux` and `batch-file`, which is contradictory. Here is a batch-file solution:

```
fc file1 file2 >nul && (echo same) || (echo different)
```

"to not report when files are different", just skip the `|| (echo different)` part